# Does teams over multiple vlans connect to a singleTeam Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, vlan

I have a startup with multiple departments. I want to create vlans according to departments through a layer 3 switch. There is this windows server machine with tfs installed. Now,will all the terminals of all departments running visual studio share the single codebase of the tfs running on the windows server? It it the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

*Now, will all the terminals of all departments running visual studio share the single codebase of the tfs running on the windows server?*

A TFS database is corresponding to a **Team Project Collection**. If all your teams are able to access your TFS server and working in same collection. Then they are actually share the same database and codebase.

TFS is also available work across multiple domains. And which could sync users from a AD domain controller.

Not much sure about your network environment. If you made large changes to your network configuration, you have to make sure all of your network infrastructure services work again, like DHCP and DNS. Without that, you can't reliably resolve names to IP addresses.

If you changed the IP address of the server the TFS server is sitting on, you'll have to make sure it's running and configured properly. Check the Application Eventlog on that server to see if there is anything wrong with TFS starting or with the SQL server that it's databases are on.